# NSString long date format to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

I have a string in the form of

"11:00AM, Saturday August 21, 2010"

How do I convert this to an NSDate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

`NSString *input = @"11:00AM, Saturday August 21, 2010";

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [df setDateFormat:@"hh:mma, EEEE MMMM d, yyyy"];

    NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    [df2 setDateFormat:@"MMMM yyyy"];

    NSDate *date = [df2 stringFromDate:[df dateFromString:input]];`

And format your date object as you want.
 http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: if this was the right solution for you, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: The first DateFormatter you set up was fine, (df). I don't know what you were doing with the second date formatter, but the first one worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this format. `-(NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)string` is the method you want to use then.

Comment: any idea of how to configure that date formatter for such a request?